# How to display the time only without including date in the textbox in C# window form?

Tags: c#, window

I retrieved the data from the database is include not only date but also time. I only want to dislay the time, like AM PM include, not include the date in the textbox in C# window form. For example,
The textbox display the
09/08/2017 14:00:00 PM
I want the textbox to display the 
14:00:00 PM
in C# window form.

Comment: is the column type `Date` in you database table?

Comment: You can convert the string to a DateTime (if the date column in the database is Date then your result may not need converting) & then use a [Standard Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) like T to convert the time to a string or a [Custom Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) if it is not exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can simply use a split function like:

Try this :

```
var dates = "09/08/2017 14:00:00 PM ".split(" ");
```

You will get your required value:
`dates[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var Timeonly = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 10:00:00 AM");
 var time = Timeonly - Timeonly .Date;
```

Comment: "time" is a TimeSpan not the time of day & it will display as such - so no AM or PM which OP has said he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you get DateTime object from data access layer then you can simply use `ToLongTimeString()` e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` and use current culture. If you want to specific culture then use `ToString()` with culture object provided like

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```